# how to import Redux Form from other js file

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to implement dynamic registration page using redux form. But I'm getting the error "handleSubmit is not a function". I've checked few solutions in Stack Overflow. I've tried like that but this mentioned error in my browser console I'm getting while running my app in my local server.

My code is:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const FIELDS = {
  user_name: {
    type: 'input',
    label: 'User Name'
  },
  email: {
    type: 'input',
    label: 'Email ID'
  },
  password: {
    type: 'password',
    label: 'Password'
  }
};

export class SignUp extends Component {
  onSubmit(props) {
    alert('Form Submitted');
  }

  renderField(fieldConfig, field) {
    const fieldHelper = this.props.fields[field];
    return (
      <div className={`form-group ${fieldHelper.touched && fieldHelper.invalid ? 'has-danger' : '' }`}>
        <label>{fieldConfig.label}</label>
        <fieldConfig.type type="text" className="form-control" {...fieldHelper} />
        <div className="text-help">
          {fieldHelper.touched ? fieldHelper.error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(props => this.onSubmit(props))}>
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
          {_.map(FIELDS, this.renderField.bind(this))}
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sing Up</button>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-denger">Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};
  _.each(FIELDS, (type,field) => {
    if (!values[field]) {
      error[field] = `Enter a ${field}`;
    }
  });
  return errors;
}


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'SignUp',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  validate
})(SignUp);
```

and my other js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
........
import { reduxForm } from "../components/SignUp/SignUp";

export class GuestHeader extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div>
              ..............
              <Route path={"/SignUp"} component={reduxForm} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code looks correct to me; I slightly simplified it in this sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/71kjq1wo71 and it seems to work...

Comment: redux-form-website-template is not working for me

Comment: As far as I see this is wrong: ```import { reduxForm } from "../components/SignUp/SignUp";```, try replace it with ```import SignUp from "../components/SignUp/SignUp";```

Comment: I've changed. But not getting the result. And in my console no error as well.

Comment: Then, I suggest you to prepare some sandbox to reproduce the error.

Comment: This is wrong: `import { reduxForm } from "../components/SignUp/SignUp";`, it should look something like this: `import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';` This may not fix your problem, but the code is wrong, fix it.